# An Editor bug that I'm really getting tired of

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editor

I'm using Chrome 14.0.835.186 on MacOS 10.6.8, and I frequently have trouble editing my posts because the editor, when loading the post content, has a tendency to omit things.

Here is a recent example, from this morning, which actually significantly derailed my answer. This one doesn't seem to happen consistently, though.

```
1. `http:http` results in ``
```

Here's another one. Links, all of them, just about every time I can remember:

```
This is some text and now [this_thing_here][1] is a hyperlink.

  [1]: http://www.google.com
```

Which becomes, upon opening the edit page:

```
This is some text and now [this_thing_here][1] is a hyperlink.

  [1]:
```

Notice how the link href get's omitted?

Anyway, has anybody else experienced this problem, or am I the only one?

I will do my best to provide any additional information needed to get this darn issue fixed.

Comment: Norepro here.  Same Chrome - Win7, though.

Comment: Eh, do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: Yes, I do. I will do some experimenting with incognito and disabling them, and update my question later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't reproduce this. I suggest trying a clean install of a different browser, or disabling all extensions in your Chrome.

Comment: The error is being caused by a Chrome extension known as Linkification. Disabling has solved the problem, thanks for the tip. Adding stackoverflow.com to the extension's configurable blacklist also solved the problem.